# Angular ngneat spectator service testing

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, angular-test, angular-spectator

I am having trouble testing a service injected into an Angular component.

Here is an example scenario I am facing. Let's say I have `SampleComponent` that has `SampleService` injected. I want to test whether running `handleAction()` in `SampleComponent` calls `SampleService.doSomething()`.

```js
@Component({
...
})
export class SampleComponent {
    constructor(private sampleService: SampleService) { }

    handleAction(): void {
        this.sampleService.doSomething();
    }
}
```

#### Trial 1

```js
import { SampleComponent } from './sample.component';
import { waitForAsync } from "@angular/core/testing";
import { createComponentFactory, Spectator } from "@ngneat/spectator";

describe('SampleComponent', () => {
    let spectator: Spectator<SampleComponent>;
    let component: SampleComponent;

    const createComponent = createComponentFactory({
        component: SampleComponent,
        imports: [ CommonModule ],
        declarations: [ SampleComponent ],
        mocks: [ SampleService ]
    });

    beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
        spectator = createComponent();
        component = spectator.component;
    }));

    it("should call SampleService.doSomething", () => {
        const sampleService = spectator.inject(SampleService);
        const spySampleServiceFunction = spyOn(sampleService, "doSomething").and.callThrough();

        component.handleAction();
        expect(spySampleServiceFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

Regardless of whether I use `and.callThrough()` for spyObject or not, I get the following error.

`Error: <spyOn>: doSomething has already been spied upon`

#### Trial 2

```js
// same until 'it'
it("should call SampleService.doSomething", () => {
    const sampleService = spectator.inject(SampleService);

    component.handleAction();
    expect(sampleService.doSomething).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

I get the following error.

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'doSomething')
```

#### Trial 3

If I put `SampleService` in `providers`, errors are caused due to the dependencies injected to `SampleService`.

Any sort of advice and suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: shouldnt `SampleService.doSomething();` in your component be `this. sampleService.doSomething(); `

Comment: @DrakeAnglin yes, it's a mistake. Just edited it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually on the second look, the code was getting the service as an `Input` not a dependency, so that was why the test wasn't working. But, I'll post the final code anyways.

```js
import { SampleComponent } from './sample.component';
import { waitForAsync } from "@angular/core/testing";
import { createComponentFactory, Spectator, SpyObject } from "@ngneat/spectator";

describe('SampleComponent', () => {
    let spectator: Spectator<SampleComponent>;
    let component: SampleComponent;
    let sampleService: SpyObject<SampleService>;

    const createComponent = createComponentFactory({
        component: SampleComponent,
        imports: [ CommonModule ],
        declarations: [ SampleComponent ],
        mocks: [ SampleService ]
    });

    beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
        spectator = createComponent();
        component = spectator.component;
        
        sampleService = spectator.inject(SampleService);
        sampleService.doSomething.and.callThrough();
        
        spectator.detectChanges();
    }));

    it("should call SampleService.doSomething", () => {
        component.handleAction();
        expect(spySampleServiceFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```